# FOSUser + LexikJWT still returning 401 (Full authentication is required to access this resource.)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm working on a project that implements two-level authentication (username + password) and TOTP authentication using the FOS User bundle. Additionally, I'm integrating a REST API using the FOSRest bundle. To handle authentication for this API, I'm using the Lexik/JWT-Authentication-Bundle. However, I've encountered a route conflict when attempting to authenticate, resulting in an error message.

Security.yaml

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
            algorithm: 'auto'
            cost:      15
    role_hierarchy:
   
   
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SOGETI_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_EM: ROLE_USER

enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    api_login:
        pattern: ^/api/login_check$
        stateless: true
        
    # dev:
    #     pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    #     security: false   
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            enable_csrf: true
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
        entry_point: form_login 
        jwt: ~ # Allow JWT authentication to be used alongside form-based authentication for the main firewall
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~ # Use JWT authentication as the entry point for the API firewall Add any additional JWT-specific configuration for API routes here
    
access_control:
    
    - { path: ^/login$, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/css, role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/register, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EM] }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

    - { path: ^/api/login_check$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

- routes.yaml:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
    # prefix:   /{_locale}
    # requirements:
    #     _locale: en|fr

fos_user_registration_register:
    path:      /{_locale}/register
    defaults:  { _controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::registerAction }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

fos_user_change_password:
    path:      /{_locale}/change-password
    defaults:  { _controller: App\Controller\ChangePasswordController::changePasswordAction }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

fos_user_registration_confirm:
    path:      /confirm/{token}
    defaults:  { _controller: App\Controller\DefaultUserController::confirmUserAction }

fos_user_registration_confirmed:
    path:      /confirmed
    defaults:  { _controller: App\Controller\DefaultUserController::savempsAction }

fos_user_security_login:
    path:      /login
    defaults:  { _controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction }

fos_user_security_check:
    path:      /{_locale}/login_check
    defaults:  { _controller: fos_user.security.controller:checkAction }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

fos_user_security_logout:
    path:      /{_locale}/logout
    defaults:  { _controller: fos_user.security.controller:logoutAction }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr

api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

Comment: if I'm right, JWT use a public and private key to make it work. Not totally sure by the way